# Change of listRowBackground in SwiftUI for NavigationLink doesn't change the full background

Tags: swiftui

Code is the following:

```swift
List(selection: $selectedBoard) {
    ForEach(boards) { board in
        NavigationLink(tag: board, selection: $selectedBoard) {
            BoardView(board: board)
        } label: {
            Text(board.name ?? "Board")
         }
        .listRowBackground(self.selectedBoard == board ? Color.App.boardSelection : Color.App.boardBackground)
```

The effect is the following:

[image]

See the gray space on the left and right? This is the accent color that I don't know how to remove. The whole row should be the same, uniform color of a bit lighter black.

Working example: https://github.com/igr/Clmn

https://github.com/igr/Clmn/blob/main/Clmn/Views/BoardList/BoardsNavigationListView.swift#L32

Comment: show a minimal reproducible example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. 
The code you show is not enough to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when `List` is used in `NavigationView` for iteration of `NavigationLink` elements.

This seems to be a bug.